# What happens to a native DLL when placed in the Bin folder of an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, dll

I'd like to know what happens when a native (read: non-.NET) DLL is placed within the Bin folder of an ASP.NET application. Specifically I have ~two questions (I won't bog down these straight forward questions with the specifics of my situation):

Does ASP.NET store the DLL's in memory? Is this why a) I can't delete the files and b) changing permissions on the files doesn't affect ASP.NET's ability to read them?

Also, is it possible for a native DLL in one ASP.NET application bin folder to affect a completely different ASP.NET application? Because that certainly seems to be happening with two of my applications. Is a native DLL a resource that is subsequently used by the ASP.NET client in any context?

Comment: I think native .DLLs have to be "registered" with the host system.  This is probably why you are seeing effects in multiple applications.

Comment: Does the ASP.NET client register them if they hadn't previously been registered?

Comment: "Native" DLLs only have to be registered if they are COM/OCX DLLs, but not if they are native Win32 DLLs.

Comment: @Esteban No, I never did, and unfortunately, I've since left the job where I was having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

for me, if the CLR comes across a non-net dll in the bin folder, it will try to load it and not be able to, and the compiler will show you the YSOD.

if you are having trouble deleting the dlls, i would suggest iisreset - works for me when i come across files i can't delete.

Comment: I've used the Unlocker tool to kill processes that hold files that I can't delete :) http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/

Answer (score 1):

1. You won't be able to delete any files in the Bin folder of your app until you stop IIS.
2. Your other app may be dying because it's sharing an `AppPool` with the application that's loading the "bad" DLL; this may in turn be killing (read shutting down) the `AppPool`. Make sure each site is running on a different pool and you shouldn't seen any problems on the other site.